# Column widths when columns around

Tags: tables, arrays

Similar to my last question but now I'm uncertain as to why the column widths have changed. The last column in the first table now needs to be the first column in the 2nd table. How can I keep the column the same size when moving them around? How do you use the & & symbols to achieve this? The table on top is the original, the table below is what I'm working on.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow, array}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{bm}

\geometry{tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\fancyhead{}
\lhead{}
\chead{\fontsize{7}{12} \selectfont \textbf{Remarks on Notation, Size, and Shape of the Operating Matricies and Row and Column Vectors in ROSE} \\ \fontsize{6}{9} \selectfont Carl Ledbetter 3 June 2019}
\rhead{}

\title {Remarks on Notation, Size, and Shape of the Operating Matricies and Row and Column Vectors in ROSE}
\author{Carl Ledbetter}
\date{3 June 2019}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\[
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
 \hline
0 & \hat{0}_n  & \hat{0}_{(m+1)} \\
 \hline
d & \hat c  &  \\
\cdashline{1-2}
 & &  \\
\bar{b} & A & \\
 &  &   \multirow{-4.2}{*}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$}   \\                       
\hline
 \end{array}
\]


\[
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
 \hline
\hat{0}_{(m+1)} & \hat{0}_n  & 0 \\
\hline
& \hat c & d \\
\cdashline{2-3}
& & \\
\multirow{-4.2}{*}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$} & & \\
& A & \bar{b} \\

\hline
 \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: in both tables you specify the first two columns as 3cm and the third the width of its content. But content in the third column differs so the third column is different width.

Comment: presumably you want to move the `|c|` to column one in the second table.

Comment: I'm unsure of where to move the |c| to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying three columns as

```
|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|
 >{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|
 c|
```

That is two at 3.5cm and one natural width, you want

```
|c|
 >{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|
 >{\centering\arraybackslash\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|
```

The `\arraybackslash` is to restore `\\`  to its "end of table row" meaning, as `\centering` redefines it to make a centred line break.

Comment: That makes sense but now I am getting "there's no line here to end" error

Comment: @ErikaOlsen use `\centering\arraybackslash` sorry, I'll ammend the answer

Comment: @ErikaOlsen see updated answer

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Is there a way to center the A & B within their boxes?